# Magento combine table rates with per product shipping

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm using the table rates (weight) to calculate the shipping costs. There are some products that have fixed shipping costs.

For example. I've a total of 7 products in my cart. 5 of these products are covered by the shipping rates. These 5 products have a total weight of 20kg. The costs of 20kg is €20.

The other 2 products have a shipping costs of €10 a piece. The weight of these 2 products must not be include into the table rates.

So the total costs of shipping is:

€20 for the first 5 products
and 2 times €10 for the last 2 products

So the total shipping costs has to be €40

Does anyone know an extension/ a way to fix this problem?

Comment: I need the same concept. The extension refered by Kuba_ceg is somewhat costly. Is there anything other extension for this concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this extension it looks like it should have all requirements http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/WebShopApps/extension/1357/webshopapps-product-matrix-shipping